# Textarea which retains <br /> tags

Tags: php, html, tinymce

I'm looking for a way to retain the paragraphs or `<br />` tags in textareas - preferably using only PHP.

I understand there is TinyMCE however it seems as though you can't remove the formatting bar - the only formatting I want kept are the paragraphs or `<br />` tags. I don't want the user to do anything else.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Could you show an example of what's the desired outcome for some example input? How are you processing the form?

Comment: you need to write you own editor in javascript. you can make 2 views, one would be the html (so that will contain the textbox) and another will be for viewing it. and you just need to render the html code the way you want it (so check and see if users are inputing anything other than <br /> tags and if they are either remove them or change them to text to avoid running them.

Comment: I am submitting the form to a PHP file via POST. The data will be stored in MYSQL, then re-displayed to users, but I need that data to retain the line breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to actually be looking for [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php), sir. Try:

```
$sanitized_text_from_database = ...
echo nl2br($sanitized_text_from_database);
```

Answer (score 2):

`<textarea>`s have nothing to do with `<br>` or `<p>` tags.
Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in a `<textarea>` generates a normal newline.

It sounds like you're actually asking to display the non-HTML text from a `<textarea>` in a way that preserves newlines.

Comment: Think of what I need just like writing an email. Each time the user presses Enter that line break will be retained and displayed to the recipient. When the form has been passed to PHP via POST, it seems to lose all line breaks.

Comment: @Dan: Wrong.  The line breaks are preserved, but you're (probably) displaying them as HTML, which ignores newlines.

Comment: @Dan You have to understand the difference between a `\n` line break and a `<br>` line break...

Comment: @SLaks: You are right. I just needed PHP to convert the \n line break to <br />. nl2br() did that nicely